# Equivalence Relations of Power Sets

Tags: relations

I am trying to understand how $\mathrm W$ is an equivalence relation.

Let $A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ and $B = \{1,2,3,4\}$.

Let $\mathrm W$ be the relation on $P(A)$ defined by: \begin{equation}
\forall X, Y \in P(A), X \mathrm R Y \Leftrightarrow |X \cap B| = |Y \cap B|
\end{equation}

Comment: Yes, I was trying to prove that it is reflexive. I was thinking that it is not reflexive since, X = {1,2,3,4,5} and Y = {1,2,3,4} then |X $\cap$ B| = 4 = |Y $\cap$ B|. But element 5 in X cannot point to itself. However, that contradicts from the question that is claiming it is an equivalence relation. Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean "element 5 in X cannot point to itself"?

Comment: Remember what it means to be reflexive... it means that elements are related to themselves.  The elements in this case are *the elements of $\mathcal{P}(A)$*, NOT the numbers 1,2,3,...  Now... let $X\in\mathcal{P}(A)$.  Is $X \mathcal{R} X$?  In other words is $|X\cap B|=|X\cap B|$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\forall X\in \mathcal P(A),\forall Y\in\mathcal P(A): \Big[X\operatorname R Y \iff \lvert X\cap B\rvert = \lvert Y\cap B\rvert\Big]$$

In English: "Any two subsets of $A$, are said to be $\operatorname R$ related if their intersections with $B$ have the same cardinality."

The relation $\operatorname R$ is an equivalence relation if it is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.   You have gotten that far, but don't seem to know what these properties *are*.

> Yes, I was trying to prove that it is reflexive. I was thinking that it is not reflexive since, $X = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $Y = \{1,2,3,4\}$ then $|X \cap B| = 4 = |Y \cap B|$. But element 5 in X cannot point to itself. However, that contradicts from the question that is claiming it is an equivalence relation. Am I missing something?

I'm not *entirely* sure what you mean by "element 5 in X cannot point to itself".   We are discussing relations between *subsets of* $A$, not betwixt elements of those subsets.

Reflexivity means that identity always infers a relationship, $\forall X\,\forall Y:(X=Y)\to (X\operatorname R Y)$, however the converse is not necessary; a relationship need not imply an identity.   It is possible for two distinct sets to be in a reflexive relation.   (Or an equivalence relation for that matter; equivalence is not necessarily identity.)

In short, the following means that $\operatorname R$ is reflexive:$$\forall X\in\mathcal P(A): X\operatorname R X$$

So to ascertain that $\operatorname R$ is reflexive you must assess whether *all* subsets of $A$ (aka elements of $\mathcal P(A)$) are related to themselves.   Does the following hold?$$\forall X\in\mathcal P(A): \lvert X\cap B\rvert =\lvert X\cap B\rvert$$

Similarly symmetry is ascertained by $$\begin{align}\forall X\in\mathcal P(A)~\forall Y\in\mathcal P(A) &: (\lvert X\cap B\rvert = \lvert Y\cap B\rvert) \to (\lvert Y\cap B\rvert = \lvert X\cap B\rvert)\\ &\Updownarrow\\ \forall X\in\mathcal P(A)~\forall Y\in\mathcal P(A) &: (X\operatorname R Y) \to (Y\operatorname R X)\end{align}$$

And then there is transitivity.
$$\begin{align}\forall X\in\mathcal P(A)~\forall Y\in\mathcal P(A)~\forall Z\in\mathcal P(A) &: \Big(\big((\lvert X\cap B\rvert = \lvert Y\cap B\rvert) \wedge (\lvert Y\cap B\rvert = \lvert Z\cap B\rvert)\big)~\to~ (\lvert X\cap B\rvert = \lvert Z\cap B\rvert)\Big)\\ &\Updownarrow\\ \forall X\in\mathcal P(A)~\forall Y\in\mathcal P(A)~\forall Z\in\mathcal P(A) &: \Big(\big((X\operatorname R Y)\wedge(Y\operatorname R Z)\big)~ \to ~(X\operatorname R Z)\Big)\end{align}$$

Comment: With that, I am right to say that there are 6 equivalence classes for R.

Comment: There are $5$. @C.E.

Comment: How did you arrive with 5? I would suppose an empty set would be counted as one too.

Comment: Since $B=\{1,2,3,4\}$, then there are only five possible sizes of which the intersection of $B$ and a subset of $A$ might have. @C.E. These enumerate the equivalence classes that partition $A$.

Comment: To clarify, the number of possible size is influenced by the number of elements in sets. For instance if B = {1,2,3,4,5} instead, the possible sizes will be 6 instead?

Comment: Yes, just so, @C.E.

Answer (score 1):

(Answering your comment.)  Yes, you are missing something.  What you are missing is that this is a relation between **sets**, not between individual elements.  So the statement
$$X\ {\rm R}\ Y$$
only makes sense (whether true or false) if $X$ and $Y$ are sets.  It does not make sense, and is irrelevant to the question, if you try to take $X$ as a single element such as $5$.

But (at the risk of further confusion) it does make sense if $X$ is **a set containing a single element** such as $\{5\}$.  Note that $\{5\}$ is not the same as $5$!!!